# Extracting integer multiplicative factors from the sum of certain sets of (finite-precision) real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, nt.number-theory

Update based on Michael's answer (thanks again!) - Can the LLL or PSLQ algorithms provide a (knowably - i.e. not just incidental) unique solution for the set of integer multiplicative factors?  Are there other algorithms (perhaps with worse run-time complexities) that can?

Imagine that one has a set of 'n' finite-precision real numbers - (r_1, r_2, ..., r_n), each with an associated positive integer multiplicative factor, (i_1, i_2, ..., i_n).  Here, one only has access to the values in the set of real numbers, as well as the sum of the real numbers multiplied by their corresponding multiplicative factors, 'S', i.e. - Sum(i_1*n_1, i_2*n_2, ..., i_n*r_n).

What's the most efficient way to test that the sum of a particular set of real numbers will (or, obviously, will not) always allow us to extract a unique solution for the set of integer multiplicative factors?  Or to find/do this with fewest restrictions on the values of the integer multiplicative factors?

In the case that this has a very simple answer, apologies.

(Edit - Changed "each with an associated "set of" positive integer multiplicative factors" --> "each with an associated positive integer multiplicative factor".  One finite-precision real number 'r_k' has one integer multiplicative factor 'i_k'.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [integer relation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm), such as the [LLL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm).

Comment: Michael - thank you!  However, from reading the description, I am not sure that the LLL or PSLQ algorithm will provide a solution that is unique?  Can we insure that there is no 'lost information' for integer multiplicative factors from the summation operation?  

Comment: I don't know; I just know the names of the algorithms, I haven't actually used them.  Sorry I can't be of more help.